# Regular Expression Get US Zip Code

Tags: python, regex

How do I "extract" zip code (US) from the following string?

```
import re
address = "Moab, UT 84532"
postal_code = re.match('^\d{5}(-\d{4})?$', address)
print postal_code
```

Comment: See the link [http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2](http://regexlib.com/REDetails.aspx?regexp_id=2)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, you are using match, which will match only from the beginning of the string: see http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#matching-vs-searching

Also, even if you were using search, you are not grabbing the group that includes the 5 digits that are guaranteed to be there.

Lastly, even if you were using search, starting your regex with a carat ^ will force it to search from the beginning, which obviously won't work in your case.

```
>>> postal_code = re.search(r'.*(\d{5}(\-\d{4})?)$', address)
>>> postal_code.groups()
('84532', None)
```

Comment: Sberry, why do you include the '.\*' in your search pattern? Won't the '.\*' match the "Moab, UT " part of the address so search would end up matching the entire ""Moab, UT 84532"? Don't have access to a computer with python at the moment so I can't test it out. Besides that though, your pattern looks spot on and I like that it will catch the extended zip codes as well.

Comment: This regex gives a false positive for "-00000"

Answer (score 6):

Assuming the zip code is always 5 digit (is that the case in the US is it not?)

```
re.match('\d{5}$', address)
```

will do.

Comment is right about match vs search and if I want to include the extra 4 chars:

```
re.search('\d{5}(-\d{4})?$', address)
```

should do it.

Comment: I disagree.  Us zip codes can include an additional 4 digits.  Also, using match in this case will not yield the correct results as it will match from the beginning of the string.

Answer (score 2):

you can use :

```
postal_code = re.match('^.*?(\d+)$', address)
if postal_code is not None:
    print postal_code.group(1)
```

Answer (score 1):

This one works perfectly for all these formats:

99999-9999

99999 9999

99999

```
address = '123 Main St, 12345-5678 USA'
re.search('(\d{5})([- ])?(\d{4})?', address).groups()
```

The result is: ('12345', '-', '5678')

To get the whole match, use:

```
re.search('(\d{5})([- ])?(\d{4})?', address).group(0)
```

And group(1) & group(3) contain both portions of the zip code. I use match instead since I am applying this to a field that contains a zip code only. I also added ^ $ at the beginning and end respectively for this case.

```
zip_code = '12345-6655'
re.match('^(\d{5})([- ])?(\d{4})?$', zip_code).group(0)
```